# AJAX get-Request not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to call a php-script via this code:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) 
    {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xml, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }});
```

The .php-File only contains

> echo "TEST"

The problem is: All I get displayed in the console is a weird block of question marks...

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the console output? Also what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: version is 3.3.1 - Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/jm68sp (Looks just like a encoded file to mee...)

Comment: Very strange. Try using google chrome's network tab in the developer panel. If you initiate your AJAX request while on this tab you can see exactly what is being sent and received from the server.

Comment: Also, from the jQuery documentation: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: Try `return 'test';` instead of echoing it..  You may also need to use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @Noah Rose Ledesma in this case, the `success: function(data)` and `error: function(data)` are options used like callbacks.

Comment: your php script won't recognize a language construct inside of a string. try dropping the `'`. i.e. `echo "TEST";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - I spotted the problem (A long time ago, just hadn't the time to post it):

The Code was completely fine. The Problem was, however, that the path was wrong and so I sent the request to a old Test-Script that echoed an entire video...

So, if you have a similar problem: The code from above should work.